# Como mudar o posicionamento inicial do modal?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal

Como eu consigo mudar o posicionamento inicial do *Modal Box do Bootstrap*?

Gostaria que ele ficasse um pouco mais para baixo, coisa que com 3 `<br>` já resolvem, mas da maneira citada parece mais uma gambiarra, do que uma solução correta.

```html
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });

}); 

</script>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"><br><br>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" 
                   data-dismiss="modal">
                       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                       <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    Modal title
                </h4>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label"
                              for="inputEmail3">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" 
                        id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email"/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"
                          for="inputPassword3" >Password</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control"
                            id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password"/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"/> Remember me
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Modal Footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        data-dismiss="modal">
                            Close
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Save changes
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para posicionar elementos utilize *CSS*, `<br>` deve ser utilizado em quebra de linha de texto. Usei `style="margin-top:100px;"` no modal para posicionar da forma que você queria;

```html
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });

}); 

</script>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top:100px;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" 
                   data-dismiss="modal">
                       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                       <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    Modal title
                </h4>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label"
                              for="inputEmail3">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" 
                        id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email"/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"
                          for="inputPassword3" >Password</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control"
                            id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password"/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"/> Remember me
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
                
                
                
                
                
                
            </div>
            
            <!-- Modal Footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        data-dismiss="modal">
                            Close
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Save changes
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```