# Como descer um formulário?

Tags: html, css

Possuo este formulário:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Jornal Web</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="galery/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="galery/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="galery/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="galery/manifest.json">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="galery/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="assets/css/carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/login">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>Entrar no Jornal Web</h2>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group has-danger">
                    <label>Digite seu e-mail</label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email"
                               placeholder="voce@exemplo.org" required autofocus>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Digite sua senha</label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password"
                               placeholder="********" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-top: .35rem">
                <div class="form-check mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input class="form-check-input" name="remember"
                               type="checkbox">
                        <span style="padding-bottom: .15rem">Lembrar-me</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="padding-top: 1rem">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.form-control').on('focus blur', function (e) {
            $(this).parents('.form-group').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value.length > 0));
        }).trigger('blur');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

O qual estou desenvolvendo para uma página de login. Entretanto na versão *desktop*, o formulário, assim como todo a página está muito em cima, e eu gostaria de descer um pouco a posição dele.

Usei alguns `<br>` mas parece errado usar dessa maneira. Como mudar através de CSS?

Comment: Como assim descer? login modal? ou posicionamento na página? o bootstrap tem um manual bem completo, já leu a documentação? [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para posicionar elementos utilize CSS. O `<br>` deve ser utilizado em **quebra de linha de texto**, assim como o próprio nome sugere. Use por exemplo `style="padding-top: 150px;"` no seu `<body>`, para posicionar da forma que você queira, ou através da tag `<style>`:

```
body{
    padding-top: 150px;
}
```

Você também pode utilizar as medidas com porcentagem, por exemplo:

```
body{
    padding-top: 15%;
}
```

A qual traz maior responsividade à sua página e adaptação aos diferentes dispositivos, e a que recomendo utilizar.

Você também pode utilizar o [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/margin) ao invés do [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/padding) dependendo da situação:

```
body{
    margin-top: 15%;
}
```

<sub>Os valores são todos suposições, adapte ao que for necessário.</sub>

Se você não sabe a diferença entre *margin* e *padding*, recomendo a leitura [dessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189978/66203).

### Relacionada

- [Como mudar o posicionamento inicial do modal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/201076/66203)

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a lógica do *amiguinho ali de cima*, se não ficar no lugar que é suposto pra ele ficar, dá pra usar:

```
<style>
    form
    {
        margin-top:50px;
        display:table;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar:

```
<head>
    ...
    <style>
        form {
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Caso seja de sua preferencia, você também poderia utilizar a propriedade "position", com o valor "relative" e redefinindo a posição do formulário a partir da propriedade top.

```css
form{
 position: relative;
 top: 10%;
}
```

Porém, a forma mais recomendável seria por meio dos '
' ou mesmo pelo 'margin-top'.